# Unable to start Mongodb. Appears to be crashed, if yes, how to recover my data

Tags: mongodb

Below is the error when ouput when I am trying to start my local mongodb. I am unable to start it and after little exploration, I doubt my local db has been crashed. If yes, is there a way to recover it.

```
mongod --dbpath /Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/
2015-01-12T11:35:25.545-0800 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2081 port=27017 dbpath=/Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/ 64-bit host=Sridhars-MacBook-Pro.local
2015-01-12T11:35:25.546-0800 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.5
2015-01-12T11:35:25.546-0800 [initandlisten] git version: e99d4fcb4279c0279796f237aa92fe3b64560bf6
2015-01-12T11:35:25.546-0800 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx108-1 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-01-12T11:35:25.546-0800 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2015-01-12T11:35:25.546-0800 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/" } }
2015-01-12T11:35:25.547-0800 [initandlisten] journal dir=/Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/journal
2015-01-12T11:35:25.547-0800 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-01-12T11:35:25.567-0800 [initandlisten] openExisting size 12288 less than minimum file size expectation /Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/local.0
2015-01-12T11:35:25.567-0800 [initandlisten] Assertion failure false src/mongo/db/storage/data_file.cpp 112
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] 0x1006c12eb 0x1006786a2 0x100669322 0x1004d4d45 0x1004dbbc6 0x1000eba37 0x1000ec4be 0x1000ef4a0 0x100107374 0x1001075c5 0x1002f89ba 0x10029b78c 0x100000fce 0x10000444a 0x100004cc3 0x100005451 0x100000a94 0x3 
 0   mongod                              0x00000001006c12eb _ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo + 43
 1   mongod                              0x00000001006786a2 _ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc + 114
 2   mongod                              0x0000000100669322 _ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j + 274
 3   mongod                              0x00000001004d4d45 _ZN5mongo8DataFile12openExistingEPKc + 953
 4   mongod                              0x00000001004dbbc6 _ZN5mongo13ExtentManager4initEv + 200
 5   mongod                              0x00000001000eba37 _ZN5mongo8Database12openAllFilesEv + 45
 6   mongod                              0x00000001000ec4be _ZN5mongo8DatabaseC2EPKcRbRKSs + 958
 7   mongod                              0x00000001000ef4a0 _ZN5mongo14DatabaseHolder11getOrCreateERKSsS2_Rb + 834
 8   mongod                              0x0000000100107374 _ZN5mongo6Client7Context11_finishInitEv + 78
 9   mongod                              0x00000001001075c5 _ZN5mongo6Client7ContextC2ERKSsS3_b + 117
 10  mongod                              0x00000001002f89ba _ZN5mongo8runCountERKSsRKNS_7BSONObjERSsRi + 74
 11  mongod                              0x000000010029b78c _ZN5mongo14DBDirectClient5countERKSsRKNS_7BSONObjEiii + 364
 12  mongod                              0x0000000100000fce _ZN5mongo33checkIfReplMissingFromCommandLineEv + 350
 13  mongod                              0x000000010000444a _ZN5mongo14_initAndListenEi + 1290
 14  mongod                              0x0000000100004cc3 _ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi + 19
 15  mongod                              0x0000000100005451 main + 977
 16  mongod                              0x0000000100000a94 start + 52
 17  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] warning database /Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/ local could not be opened
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] DBException 0: assertion src/mongo/db/storage/data_file.cpp:112
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 0 assertion src/mongo/db/storage/data_file.cpp:112, terminating
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-01-12T11:35:25.571-0800 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2015-01-12T11:35:25.583-0800 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2015-01-12T11:35:25.584-0800 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-01-12T11:35:25.584-0800 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: `openExisting size 12288 less than minimum file size expectation /Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/local.0` doesn't sound good. Why is that file so small? Disk full? Did you tinker with the data files?

Comment: No I didn't and I never used local db. I am  trying to bickm db.Just a screen shot of my mongodata space...

Comment: ls -la
total 229424
drwxr-xr-x  10 SGudimela  staff       340 Jan 12 11:56 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 SGudimela  staff       476 Jan 12 11:56 ..
-rw-------   1 SGudimela  staff     12288 Jan  9 15:31 bickm.0
-rw-------   1 SGudimela  staff  16777216 Jan 12 11:13 bickm.ns
-rw-------   1 SGudimela  staff     12288 Dec 22 12:36 cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da.0
-rw-------   1 SGudimela  staff  16777216 Dec 22 12:36 cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da.ns
drwxr-xr-x   2 SGudimela  staff        68 Jan 12 11:35 journal

Comment: -rw-------   1 SGudimela  staff     12288 Dec 19 11:49 local.0
-rw-------   1 SGudimela  staff  16777216 Dec 19 11:49 local.ns
-rwxr-xr-x   1 SGudimela  staff         0 Jan 12 11:56 mongod.lock

Comment: Is this a standalone node, or part of a replica set / sharded cluster? From the current description it looks like a standalone server .. in which case you could try moving the `local.*` files to a different directory before starting up. In a standalone server the `local` database is only used for housekeeping (there's a 10MB collection called `startup_log`). Was there anything unusual the last time you shutdown `mongod`? (eg did your server run out of disk space, crash, ...?). The reported error is that the `local.0` file is less than the minimum expected size, so seems truncated or corrupt.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, while running db.repairDatabase({}). exception: assertion src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp:109

Answer (score 1):

```
openExisting size 12288 less than minimum file size expectation /Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/local.0
```

Indicates that your datafile `local.0` is less than the minimum file size that mongo expects.

From `Assertion failure false src/mongo/db/storage/data_file.cpp 112`, we can go to the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6.3/src/mongo/db/storage/data_file.cpp) and see that during startup, mongo did not pass a file size check.

If you start mongo with `mongod --smallfiles`, `local.0` is going to be 16MB. And your local.0 is now 1.5KB, very suspicious. This file is very likely to be corrupted. If it is the case, delete `local.0` and restart mongo should do.

Did you previously insert any data into the database? And did you modify the data files by any means? Paste the output of `ls -la /Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/` may also help

Comment: Amazingly, I got the same error on a 2.6.5 MongoDB on multiple files. Removing the file didn't help and instead resulted in "Assertion failure isOk() src/mongo/db/storage/extent.h 80" while repairing.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing error *warning database /Users/SGudimela/Workspace/mongodata/ local could not be opened*, check whether you have permission to access the data directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have important information within database and you need to recover that, try to run

**In the first terminal**

```
sudo mongod --auth --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --smallfiles
```

**In the second terminal, get the backup in**

In my case Atrium is the database name AtriumCollection is a collection of that. Please replace accordingly

```
sudo mongoexport --db Atrium -c AtriumCollection --out Atrium.json
```

After that you need to remove and reinstall MongoDB and restore your database.